# removing <?xml version="1.0" tag from XML in php

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, preg-replace

I have a function returning a xml but returns a xml with two

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
```

tags

I cannot fix the call to return it with one call. Im trying to use SimpleXMLElement so when i load this xml into simplexml it gives a error because of the duplicate tags. Anyone know how i can remove the tag before loading to xml

I have tried doing

```
$new_xml = preg_replace('/<?xml(.*)?>(.*)?<\/?>/', '', $xml);
```

I have also done (which works by the way. Just not sure if its the best way since im not sure if there may at times be more info inside the

```
  $xml = str_replace('<?xml version="1.0"?>', '', $xml);
```

Comment: Why not just fix your function which introduces the duplicate line in the first place?

Comment: I mentioned I don't have control over the fact that it returns two

Answer (score 1):

This will delete the first line up to the closing > and trailing new line character.

```
<?php
$xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n\t<tag></tag>";

     $xml = preg_replace('!^[^>]+>(\r\n|\n)!','',$xml);

echo $xml;
?>
```

It also works with other XML files that aren't version 1.0 compliant.

Answer (score 0):

@AbsoluteƵERØ's answer helped me.

In my case I was creating XML myself.

```php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->formatOutput = true;

$root = $doc->createElement('TAG1');
$doc->appendChild($root);

// ... some loop that inserts more children of TAG1 with attributes

$xml_file = 'relative/path/to/file.xml';

$doc->save($xml_file); // Here the XML file is saved along with the line that poses problems

// Read created XML
$t_xml = file_get_contents($xml_file);

// Remove first line
$t_xml = preg_replace('!^[^>]+>(\r\n|\n)!', '', $t_xml);

// Save into same file as original
file_put_contents($xml_file, $t_xml);
```

Comment: If you're creating an XML file with the DOMDocument class, and it's generating invalid XML, something has gone very wrong somewhere. Maybe you've hard-coded the `<?xml ...` line somewhere and are adding it on top of the real XML?

Comment: Clarification: In said case removal is necessary. Whilst XML created by DOMDocument is perfectly valid XML by itself (without removal), that XML is then downloaded to clients browser, and they have to upload the XML to some government site. As (at least our) government doesn't seem to be a stickler for rules - in this case standards - their upload form only accepts `.xml` that starts with to root element as defined per their documentation. So to answer @IMSoP, something really *has* gone wrong, albeit not on our part.